# Making the arraylist get method work and other problems

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, get

I am coding in blueJ. My objectives are this: 1)Write a User class

A User:

```
has a username e.g 'fj3'
has a userType which can be: 'user', 'editor' or 'admin'
has a name e.g 'Francis'
has a constructor which takes the username, userType and name as parameters
has a getUsername() method
has a getUserType() method
has a getName() method
has a setUserType() method which takes one of the user types as a parameter
```

2)Write a UserGroup class

The UserGroup class must have an ArrayList of Users.

Write a constructor for the UserGroup class. It should instantiate the ArrayList.

In UserGroup write a method called .addSampleData() which creates 10 Users and using the ArrayList's add() method put the 10 new User objects into the ArrayList.

In UserGroup write a getUser method which takes an int as a parameter and returns the User in that slot of the ArrayList.

In UserGroup write a printUsernames() method in UserGroup:

Using an enhanced for loop (see above), loop through the ArrayList and print the username and userType of each user in the ArrayList.

What I have so far is:

```
package user;
public class User{
    public enum UserType{                           
        ADMIN, EDITOR, USER;
    }

    private String id;                             
    private UserType userPermissions;               
    private String actualName;                      

    public User(String username, UserType userType, String name){
        id = username;
        userPermissions = userType;
        actualName= name;
    } 

    public String getUsername(){
        return id;
    }

    public UserType getUserType(){
        return userPermissions;
    }       

    public String getName(){
        return actualName;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType input){
        userPermissions = input;
    }
}
```

And my UserGroup class:

```
package user;
import java.util.*;
import user.User.UserType; 

public class UserGroup{

    private ArrayList<User> people;

    public UserGroup(){
        people = new Arraylist<User>();
    }

    public static void addSampleData(String username, UserType userType, String name){
        people.add(new User(username, userType,name));
    }

    public User get(int){
        return User; 
    }

    public void printUsernames(){
        for (User user: groupArray){
            System.out.printf("%s %s\n", user.getUsername(), user.getuserType);
        }
    } 
}
```

This is obviously far from being complete but I am completely stuck. My first problem is that I am unsure how to write the get method for this. Please help me with this!! I think my User class is fine but my UserGroup class is nowhere near completing all the objectives and I don't know how to do them!!

Comment: Read the javadoc for [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). There is a `get()` method. You should put a `toString` method into `User` rather than format it in the `UserGroup`. Also, consider implementing `equals` and `hashcode` as you might want to use method like `indexOf` etc...

Comment: Your get method in UserGroup class must be enhanced: give a name to the input parameter (`get(int pos)`), then return with the User record found in the right position of the ArrayList: `return people.get(pos)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good so far, some corrections:

The `addSampleData()`method should not be static, as it uses a non-static member of the class. The request also states it to add the sample data itself.

The `getUser()` is pretty straight forward then.

The `printUsernames()`method uses an unknown member.

```
public void addSampleData() {
    people.add(new User("pe3", UserType.ADMIN,"Peter"));
    people.add(new User("u987", UserType.EDITOR,"Udo"));
    people.add(new User("frank123", UserType.USER,"Frank"));
    // repeat ...
}

public User getUser(int idx) {
    return people.get(idx); 
}

public void printUsernames(){
    for (User user: people){
        System.out.printf("%s %s\n", user.getUsername(), user.getuserType);
    }
}
```

In a main method then:

```
UserGroup grp = new UserGroup();
grp.addSampleData();
grp.printUsernames();
User u1 = grp.getUser(0);
```

Comment: thank you- when I did this it says "non-static variable people cannot be referenced from a static context." I removed static from addSampleData method and that compile time error disappeared but will this lead me to future problems? Would it be better to change private Arraylist<User> people to static?

Comment: now I am getting a compiling error on my enhanced for loop saying cannot find symbol- method toArray()- how should I go about fixing this?

Comment: because you are using an unknown symbol (member variable) named `groupArray`. See my edited answer, you should use the `people` array.

Comment: fixed a few other minor errors and it all compiles =) now when I try to run it it prints out the username and usertype 2 times- is there a reason for this?

Comment: This is a new question, you can post your modified code in a new question, if you are not able to find it out yourself. Do not forget to accept helpful answers.